# Использование OpenXml при заполнении таблицы. Проблема с начальным символом

Tags: c#, openxml

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(genericPathFolder + @"\" + "TESTR.docx", true))
{
    //Find the first table in the document.
    Table table = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().First();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        TableRow row = table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            TableCell cell = row.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(j);

            RunProperties runProp = new RunProperties(); // Создаем run
            RunFonts runFont = new RunFonts();           // Создаем шрифт для run
            FontSize size = new FontSize();              // Шрифт размер

            runFont.Ascii = "ArialNarrow";               // шрифт
            size.Val = new StringValue("24");            // размер = 24/2 = 12й шрифт

            runProp.Append(runFont);
            runProp.Append(size);

            if (j == 1)
            {
                Run run = new Run(new Text("123"));
                run.PrependChild<RunProperties>(runProp);
                cell.PrependChild(new Paragraph(run));
            }
            if (j == 2)
            {
                Run run = new Run(new Text("OLOLOLOLOLOLO"));
                run.PrependChild<RunProperties>(runProp);
                cell.PrependChild(new Paragraph(run));
            }

            if (j == 3)
            {
                Run run = new Run(new Text("789"));
                run.PrependChild<RunProperties>(runProp);
                cell.PrependChild(new Paragraph(run));
            }

        }
    }            
}
```

Заполняю таблицу текстом, но почему-то, тексту в каждой ячейке предшествует отступ.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чем является этот отступ, если открыть файл в Word'е?

Comment: То-то и оно, что совсем не ясно. Если я открываю файл в Word и включаю "отобразить все знаки", то этот отступ никак не отображается. Однако, если поставить курсор перед текстом и нажать backspace, то текст занимает нормальное положение, вплотную к левой границе таблицы.

Comment: Так может это стандартный отступ первой строки? 1.25 см, вроде. Смотрите свойства абзаца

Comment: Если бы это был ответ, то я смог бы отметить его как верный! ^^ Спасибо это именно оно!